# Unit test Authentication zend2

Tags: unit-testing, zend-framework2, phpunit

I am writing unit test for zend2 authentication. I am using Doctrine2.

My test case is: Login Method Should Return True On Passing Correct Credentials.

Login is working perfactly. But when I run unit test case I found following error:

"PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method  Mock_Adapter_8d9bbc77::setIdentityValue() in.....etc ".

I tried a lot but not found any solution.Your help would be greatly appreciated.

My actual code for authentication in service:

```
$authService = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService');

$adapter = $authService->getAdapter();
$adapter->setIdentityValue($data->login);//error line
$adapter->setCredentialValue($data->password);
```

My test case:

```
public function LoginMethodShouldReturnTrueOnPassingCorrectCredentials() {

 $this->loginForm = new Login;
  $this->loginForm->init();
  $this->loginForm->get('email')->setValue('test@test.com');
  $this->loginForm->get('password')->setValue('gshafdsadf123123');
  $this->loginForm->get('loginSubmit')->setValue('Login');

  $serviceLocator = Bootstrap::getServiceManager();

  $entityManager = $serviceLocator->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');

  $entityRepositoryMock = $this->getMockBuilder('Ease\EntityRepository\User')
  ->disableOriginalConstructor()
  ->getMock();

  $entityManager->method("getRepository")
  ->willReturn($entityRepositoryMock);

  $adapterMock = $this->getMockBuilder('Zend\Authentication\Adapter\Adapter')
  ->disableOriginalConstructor()
  ->getMock();
  $adapterMock->expects($this->once())->method('setIdentityValue')->with('test@test.com');
  $adapterMock->expects($this->once())->method('setCredentialValue')->with('gshafdsadf123123');

  $authMock = $this->getMockBuilder('Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService')
  ->disableOriginalConstructor()
  ->getMock();
  $authMock->expects($this->once())->method('getAdapter')->willReturn($adapterMock);

  $serviceLocator->setService('Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService', $authMock);


  $serviceLocator->setService('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default', $entityManager);

  $userServiceInstance = $this->getUserService();
  $returnValue = $userServiceInstance->handleLoginForm($this->loginForm);
  $this->assertSame($returnValue, true);
  }
```